# If Custom Post Type Has Term

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am working with a custom post type and I have created a custom menu that I only want to display if certain taxonomy terms match or match the parent and include all child terms. I am pretty new to custom post types so I am a little lost.

The custom post type is named offers and the taxonomy is offers_category.

Before I moved things over to a custom post type I used:

```
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(1, $cat) || is_category( array( 1, 7, 9, 11) ) )
```

Which worked wonders.

Now, I am trying with:

```
if ( is_singular('offers') ||  has_term( '', 'breaks', 'entertainment' ) )

//SHOW ME THE MENU
```

But it's not quite working out.

What is the best way to achieve this with custom post types?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are using `has_term` incorrectly. The first argument passed should be the term or terms (a string for one term or an array for multiple). The second argument should be the taxonomy and the third is the post id. I'm going to assume you are trying to pass those terms. `has_term( array( 'breaks', 'entertainment'), 'offers_category', get_the_ID() )`. Where are you trying to output this menu?

Comment: @disinfor thank you. That done the trick, I am using a hook, the menu is displayed below the category description. https://gyazo.com/0a5732ea6858959fa5c4f8bf5a34922d. Thanks again.